# "BlockInput" Function is Not Working in Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a program that will click the screen wherever the user asks it to. But I want to disable mouse movement/clicking while the program performs the click, otherwise if the user is moving the mouse when the program performs the click it could drag the mouse away from where the mouse was supposed to click.

Currently I've tried using:

```
Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Boolean) As Boolean
```

&

```
Private Declare Function BlockInput Lib "user32" Alias "BlockInput" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer
```

And then calling either `BlockInput(True/False)` or `BlockInput(1/0)` depending on how I declare the `BlockInput' function.

Currently neither stops the mouse from moving when I drag it across the screen.

Is there something I need to include in my code to allow this function to work? I'm aware that disabling the mouse this way might also disable the program itself from performing the click as well but I haven't even been able to test that since I can't get that far.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I've never used that function but I wonder whether you might be misinterpreting its purpose.  The description says *"Blocks keyboard and mouse input events from reaching applications"*.  It doesn't say that Windows won't react at all to the mouse or keyboard.  If that was the case then you could easily end up in a state where you had no control over the machine at all beyond powering it off at the source.

Comment: Note that I'm not 100% sure either way as to whether that function is system-wide or not but I did see at least one person mention that it didn't work in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: I just tested it by typing `BlockInput(True)`, then `Delay(5000)`, then `BlockInput(False)`and it still lets me click in Chrome and open tabs, etc. It isn't blocking anything. And from my testing it's impossible for the program to crash in the 50 ms that the mouse is disabled, at least I've never seen it happen in the hundreds of hours of running the program.

Comment: Not to say it can't happen but I feel confident it won't lol.

Comment: I see the docs page you're referencing and you're right... This wouldn't work anyways... Is it even possible to stop a physical mouse from moving the cursor while still allowing a program to move the cursor around?

Comment: That's not a question I can answer but it seems like a dangerous thing to leave in the hands of imperfect and possibly malicious developers.  What you could do is just write code to move the mouse pointer and then generate a click at specific coordinates whether the mouse pointer is there or not.  That way, even if the user does move the mouse pointer, it will only affect things visually.

Comment: That might be do-able, thanks I'll look into doing it that way instead!

Comment: I suggest you have a look at my library called [InputHelper](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper). It has the capability of blocking both keyboard and mouse input via low-level hooks, BUT even better: You can click at a specific location on the screen without the mouse being there, so you won't actually need to block anything. So far I have only documented the hooks, but if you reference the DLL in VS and press F2 in the text editor, that will open the Object Browser where you can see all available functions. The one you're looking for is `InputHelper.WindowMessages.SendMouseClick()`

Comment: You can also check some of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3740093+%5Bvb.net%5D+InputHelper) where I've provided examples of various use cases.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that tomorrow. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! If you need any help with the library itself you can post a question on the Issue tracker on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested and made me reboot :) Careful. Working on win 10

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="BlockInput")> _
Private Shared Function BlockInput(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fBlockIt As Boolean) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BlockInput(True)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I added your code and it still lets my mouse move, click around, add tabs, open programs, etc. I added the dllimport and function, added a button that runs `BlockInput(True)`, `Delay(5000)`, then `BlockInput(False)`, still lets me do stuff the entire time. I don't get why it doesn't work for me, everyone else says it works fine. I have the `InteropServices` import, I have that for another function so that's not the issue...Maybe I just have to live with the mouse moving during click and telling users to not use their mouse while running the program :(

Comment: And you have it on form_load yes? Did it at least work for the keyboard? i want to have your machine so this kind of trick won't be working against me sometime xD

Comment: Actually my advice is to (as you said) give the user a big message telling him not to use the mouse and keyboard before the app starts is much better than blocking his input, cause if for some reason your app fails to revert the block he's going to have to reboot his machine which might make him lose his open docs..

Comment: No it isn't in form_load, I only want the mouse disabled for the ~30 ms the mouse click is occurring, and enabled for the other 99% of the time. And I think I'll still use it on my computer because it's annoying when it messes up the click while I was using the mouse, but then not have that code in the program I upload online and just tell users to not move their mouse lol.

Comment: To test if it works on your pc or not just use the code as is, if it works then there's something you have to change in your code

Answer (score 0):

Run VB.net as administrator with:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in manifest